# JAX-RS: Unable to use SoapUI while browser works

Tags: xml, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a small project to demonstrate RESTful webservices

First file:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Contact getContact() {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setFirstName("John");
    contact.setFamilyName("Doe");

    return contact;
}
```

POJO

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contact {  
    String firstName;   
    String familyName;
    String city;
    String zipCode;
    /* constructor. getter, setter 
    */
}
```

pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Calling the webservice in my browser, it works, I will get a XML-document of my contact.
I also have a valid wadl-file, which I want to import to SoapUI. All fine, but when calling the GET-method inside SoapUI, I will get a 404.

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You can check Raw tab to find out what URL is used as a service. Probably URL is wrong. Compare it with what you enter into browser.

Comment: I found out, that it's an SoapUI issue, because switching from 5.1.2 to 5.0.0 it works.